# Reduce 'configuring the compilation environment' time for Kotlin with Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

During compilation using maven, when Kotlin is running it gets stuck on '[DEBUG] Configuring the compilation environment' for a good 20-30 seconds out of 40 seconds compilation time.

Is there a way to minimise this time?

```
[INFO] Kotlin Compiler version 1.0.6-release-127
[INFO] Compiling Kotlin sources from [/Users/jacksenkline/Desktop/api/src/main/java]
[DEBUG] Classpath: /Users/jacksenkline/Desktop/api/target/api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.48/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.48.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.0.6/kotlin-stdlib-1.0.6.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-runtime/1.0.6/kotlin-runtime-1.0.6.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20160810/json-20160810.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/redis/clients/jedis/2.9.0/jedis-2.9.0.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.4.2/commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.7.0/jjwt-0.7.0.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.2/jackson-databind-2.8.2.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.2/jackson-core-2.8.2.jar
[DEBUG] Classes directory is /Users/jacksenkline/Desktop/api/target/api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
[INFO] Module name is api
[DEBUG] Invoking compiler org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler@f48d6f2 with arguments:
[DEBUG] destination=/Users/jacksenkline/Desktop/api/target/api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
[DEBUG] classpath=/Users/jacksenkline/Desktop/api/target/api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.48/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.48.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.0.6/kotlin-stdlib-1.0.6.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-runtime/1.0.6/kotlin-runtime-1.0.6.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20160810/json-20160810.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/redis/clients/jedis/2.9.0/jedis-2.9.0.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.4.2/commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.7.0/jjwt-0.7.0.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.2/jackson-databind-2.8.2.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/jacksenkline/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.2/jackson-core-2.8.2.jar
[DEBUG] includeRuntime=false
[DEBUG] jdkHome=(null)
[DEBUG] noJdk=false
[DEBUG] noStdlib=true
[DEBUG] noReflect=false
[DEBUG] module=(null)
[DEBUG] script=false
[DEBUG] kotlinHome=(null)
[DEBUG] moduleName=api
[DEBUG] jvmTarget=(null)
[DEBUG] noCallAssertions=false
[DEBUG] noParamAssertions=false
[DEBUG] noOptimize=false
[DEBUG] reportPerf=false
[DEBUG] inheritMultifileParts=false
[DEBUG] allowKotlinPackage=false
[DEBUG] skipMetadataVersionCheck=false
[DEBUG] skipRuntimeVersionCheck=false
[DEBUG] declarationsOutputPath=(null)
[DEBUG] friendPaths=(null)
[DEBUG] PLUGIN_OPTION_FORMAT=plugin:<pluginId>:<optionName>=<value>
[DEBUG] languageVersion=(null)
[DEBUG] apiVersion=(null)
[DEBUG] suppressWarnings=false
[DEBUG] verbose=true
[DEBUG] version=false
[DEBUG] help=false
[DEBUG] extraHelp=false
[DEBUG] noInline=false
[DEBUG] repeat=(null)
[DEBUG] pluginClasspaths=(null)
[DEBUG] pluginOptions=(null)
[DEBUG] freeArgs=[/Users/jacksenkline/Desktop/api/src/main/java]
[DEBUG] unknownExtraFlags=[]
[DEBUG] End of arguments
[DEBUG] Using Kotlin home directory <no_path>
[DEBUG] Configuring the compilation environment
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is misleading, it just happens to be the last message printed by the compiler before the actual compilation. So it's the compilation itself that takes the majority of time.